# HitTestObjekt in ActionScribt 3.0 doesn´t work but I don´t get any Error Messages

Tags: actionscript-3

I´m trying to make a little game in ActionScribt 3.0 for a school projekt in a kind of Pixel RPG style. I wanted to use Arrays and HitTestObjekt to create some hitboxes for the many objects in the game but it just doesn´t work and since I don´t get any error Messages or even anything in the output I just don´t know what is wrong with the code.

The most confusing thing is, that I made several test room to test different functions with hitTestObjekt and it all worked perfectly fine. But once I took this code over to the main map and changed the objects in the Arrays accordingly it just stopped working.

Here is the code I made for it so far, without the stuff for NPCs or enemyies.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Front Frame");

//luke Variablen 
var rightPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var leftPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var upPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var downPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var attackButtonPress:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var lukeAlive:Boolean = new Boolean(true);

var lukeSpeed: Number = 10;
var lukeSwordPower:Number = 10;
var lukeDirection:String = "front";




var cantGoThrough: Array = new Array();


//EventListener für Tastatur und Enter_Frame
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpListener);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, GameLoop);



loadArray();

function loadArray():void {
    cantGoThrough[0] = background_MC.HitboxZaun;

}


//------------Tastatur Key Down--------------

function keyDownListener(keyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = true;
        lukeDirection = "right";
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = true;
        lukeDirection = "left";
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = true;
        lukeDirection = "back";
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = true;
        lukeDirection = "front";
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        attackButtonPress = true;
    }
}



//------------Tastatur Key Up------------

function keyUpListener(keyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = false;
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = false;
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = false;
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = false;
    }else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        attackButtonPress = false;
    }
}

/* alte Verion von Key UP ohne Angriff
function keyUpListener(keyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = false;
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Right Frame");
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = false;
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Left Frame");
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = false;
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Front Frame");
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = false;
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Back Frame");
    }else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        attackButtonPress = false;
    }
}
*/




//---------------------------------------------------------------
//------------Game Loop, Bewegung des Spielers und der Map--------
//---------------------------------------------------------------
function GameLoop(loopEvent: Event): void {

    //------lukes und Maps Bewegung------------
    if (rightPressed) {
        if (this.luke_MC.x < 800) {
            this.luke_MC.x += lukeSpeed;
        } else if (background_MC.x > -9464) {
            this.background_MC.x -= lukeSpeed;
        }
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Walk Right Frame");
    } else if (leftPressed) {
        if (this.luke_MC.x > 200) {
            this.luke_MC.x -= lukeSpeed;
        } else if (background_MC.x < -4850) {
            this.background_MC.x += lukeSpeed;
        }
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Walk Left Frame");
    } else if (upPressed) {
        if (this.luke_MC.y > 200) {
            this.luke_MC.y -= lukeSpeed;
        } else if (background_MC.y < -2469) {
            this.background_MC.y += lukeSpeed;
        }
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Walk Back Frame");
    } else if (downPressed) {
        if (this.luke_MC.y < 500) {
            this.luke_MC.y += lukeSpeed;
        } else if (background_MC.y > -4773) {
            this.background_MC.y -= lukeSpeed;
        }
        this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Walk Front Frame");
    }
    
    else if (attackButtonPress){  
//---------------Angriff Frames und Gegner bekommt Schaden vom Schwert---------------------     
        switch (lukeDirection){
            case "left":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Attack Left Frame");
                if(luke_MC.swordLeft_MC.hitTestObject(background_MC.enemy_MC)){
                    background_MC.enemy_MC.x -= 10; //Gegner wird vom Schwert zurückgestoßen
                    enemyHealth -= lukeSwordPower; 
                }
            break;
            
            case "right":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Attack Right Frame");
                if(luke_MC.swordRight_MC.hitTestObject(background_MC.enemy_MC)){
                    background_MC.enemy_MC.x += 10; //Gegner wird vom Schwert zurückgestoßen
                    enemyHealth -= lukeSwordPower; 
                }
            break;
            
            case "front":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Attack Front Frame");
                if(luke_MC.swordFront_MC.hitTestObject(background_MC.enemy_MC)){
                    background_MC.enemy_MC.y -= 10; //Gegner wird vom Schwert zurückgestoßen
                    enemyHealth -= lukeSwordPower; 
                }
            break;
                
            case "back":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Attack Back Frame");
                if(luke_MC.swordBack_MC.hitTestObject(background_MC.enemy_MC)){
                    background_MC.enemy_MC.y += 10; //Gegner wird vom Schwert zurückgestoßen
                    enemyHealth -= lukeSwordPower; 
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch(lukeDirection){
            case "left":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Left Frame");
                break;
            
            case "right":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Right Frame");
                break;
            
            case "front":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Front Frame");
                break;
            
            case "back":
                this.luke_MC.gotoAndStop("Stand Back Frame");
                break;
    
        }
    }
    



//---------Hittest für Objecte etc.--------------

    for (var i : int = 0; i< cantGoThrough.length; i++){
            if (luke_MC.footBox_MC.hitTestObject(cantGoThrough[i])) {
            switch (lukeDirection) {
                case "left":
                    lukeSpeed = 0;
                    luke_MC.x += 10;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    lukeSpeed = 0;
                    luke_MC.x -= 10;
                    break;
                case "back":
                    lukeSpeed = 0;
                    luke_MC.y += 10;
                    break;
                case "front":
                    lukeSpeed = 0;
                    luke_MC.y -= 10;
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            lukeSpeed = 10;
        }
    }
```

This is the first time I´m asking a question here, I hope I did it right.

Comment: Might be worth isolating your issue a little more and identifying which parts of the code you are having issues with. Specific questions get much more attention than a big dump of code. Eg are your keyboard listeners working? is your character moving? is your game loop executing? Is background_MC.HitboxZaun a valid sprite?

Comment: @Michael, Charakter moves perfectly, there are no problems with the listeners or the game loop, the only thing that isn´t workink for no appearent reason are the hitboxes, but I don´t know if the other code has anthing to do with the hitboxes not working, so I´m not sure how much I can really cut out here. ^-^;

Comment: So is this line never evaluating to true: luke_MC.footBox_MC.hitTestObject(cantGoThrough[i])? Have you confirmed you have content in footbox and in cantGoThrough[i] ?

Comment: @Michael Jup, I still don´t know what the error was, though by now it startet working after I rewrote the whole code that belongs to the hitboxes. ^^;